# Store an array of percentage values from a "for loop" to create a pie chart

Tags: python, arrays, append, pie-chart

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
students = [6,3,1,8,2]

a=[]
for s in students:
    a.append((s/20)*100)

values =[]
for b in a:
    values.append(b)
print(values)

values = [30, 15, 5 , 40, 10]  # Need to be the array of % values. Want to grab values from the print values
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'lightcoral', 'red']

plt.pie(values, labels=[6,3,1,8,2], colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
```

What I am trying to do is that read in values from the array named "students", and use those numbers to get a percent value of each of those number. The total number of students are 20, if we add all the numbers in the array. So, for ex: if we want to know what % of students is 1, then as I have it setup in the first for loop, it takes the number, it our case 1, we divide that by 20 and multiply by 100 to get the %. The output is:

```
30.0
15.0
5.0
40.0
10.0
```

Furthermore, now I want to store those values in a separate array, so that I can use all those % values when I plot my pie chart. However, I keep getting an error, and I don't know how to solve it. The error is:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Please help me so that I can get a graph same or similar to the one in the image below. I created it using excel.

http://oi57.tinypic.com/14ch2m0.jpg

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's failing on this line:

```
for b in a:
```

I suspect you wanted to have `a` be a list, but it is a number calculated above:

```
a = (s/20)*100
```

So you might want to have

```
a=[]
for s in students:
    a.append((s/20)*100)
```

Comment: I am not really sure what to do. I have tried multiple ways. I mean if there is a way to directly have those output % values to create the pie chart, then that will work too.

Comment: @user5403501: I've extended my answer.

Comment: I replaced both the for loops I had with your last code, and the result is giving me now is "None" five times.

Comment: @user5403501: Only the first for loop needs to be replaced.

Comment: Okay. I did that, and now it is giving me: `[30.0]
[30.0, 15.0]
[30.0, 15.0, 5.0]
[30.0, 15.0, 5.0, 40.0]
[30.0, 15.0, 5.0, 40.0, 10.0]`   I also changed that b+1 to b.

Comment: @user5403501: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: @ Vaughn Cato: I was expecting single values to be displayed in one array. This -> `[30.0
15.0
5.0
40.0
10.0]`  I am perfectly fine with what you gave me if and only if it can take every value from that last array of all those printed arrays and plot them in the pie chart as I want.

Comment: @user5403501: Move the `print(values)` to after the loop.

Comment: @ Vaughn Cato: Awesome that works. How about the pie chart ? This is the first time I am making a pie chart, so it is a little hard.

Comment: @user5403501: That would be a different question.